# jquery generate events over foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I'm programming appointment planer and still struggling with the issue that javascript doesn't generate events and prints the code just in plain text, so at first I have one php function which fetches all appointments from the sql database and generates javascript code

```
<script>
    function getEventData() {
    <?php
        function showAppointments($von, $bis){
            $link = OpenDB();
            try {
            $query = 'SELECT termin_id, client, dateFrom, dateTill, title, descri FROM termin WHERE dateFrom BETWEEN :von AND :bis';
            $statement = $link->prepare($query);
            $statement->bindValue(':von', $von, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindValue(':bis', $bis, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->execute();

            $row = $statement->fetchAll();
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                p($e);
            }
            CloseDB($link);

            return $row;
        } 
    if(empty($von) && empty($bis)) {
                $von = date("Y.m.j",strtotime("monday this week"));
                $bis = date("Y.m.j",strtotime("sunday this week"));
             }
            if(isset($_POST['last_week'])){
                $von = date("Y.m.j",strtotime("previous monday"));
                $bis = date("Y.m.j",strtotime("previous sunday"));
             }
            if(isset($_POST['next_week'])){
                $von = date("Y.m.j",strtotime("next monday"));
                $bis = date("Y.m.j",strtotime("next sunday"));
            }
            $rows = showAppointments($von, $bis);

      echo "const appointments = [";
      for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($rows); $i++) {
          $columns = array_values($rows[$i]);
          echo "[";

          for($j=0; $j< sizeof($columns); $j++){          
             echo "'".$columns[$j]."'";
             if( $j < sizeof($columns)-1) echo ",";
          }
           echo "]";

    if( $i < sizeof($rows)-1) echo ",";    
        }

            echo "];";
    ?>
then all events are generated by jquery and returned

    return { 

             events:[

            $.each(appointments, function(index, row){

                    eval("{'id':"+ row[0] + ",'client':"+ row[1] +",'start':" + new Date(row[2])+",'end': "+ new Date(row[3]) +",'title':'"+ row[4] +"','description':'"+ row[5] +"'}");

            });

            ]}}
</script>
```

the code in foreach is printed as plain text, how can I fix the issue? it should actually print something like

```
{'id':1, 'start': new Date(year, month, day, 12), 'end': new Date(year, month, day, 13, 30),'title':'Lunch with Mike'}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, is your php code visible in the browser or?

Comment: php code isn't visible, but the code in the foreach in jquery is printed as plain text

Comment: I still don't really get your question, but are you expecting the php to be executed each time with your jQuery / JS?

Comment: yes php code works fine and it should be always executed because it fetches all actual appointments of the week, the problem is still the jquery foreach code which doesn't seem to work

Comment: I found out that javascript cannot generate javascript code, only php can. gotta find another solution

Answer (score 1):

you should try the Jquery.each outside Events and then use eval(Array.join); in JavaScript, that should work